# iTunes half-star ratings gone from iOS7

Tags: itunes, ios, music.app, ratings

I had enabled half-star ratings in iTunes: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/itunes-half-star-rating/

However since iOS7 has been released, the half-star ratings don't appear in Music app anymore. Instead they appear to be rounded down.

Does anyone have any idea/official word on this?

Answer (score 1):

I haven’t seen any official announcement about this, but since it’s an undocumented setting, it’s not surprising that the functionality would’ve silently disappeared. If you’d like it back you might consider filing an [enhancement request](http://bugreport.apple.com).